# Sequelize - define 3-way many-to-many relationship with out creating intermediate join model?

Tags: sequelize.js

I have three models `Teacher`, `Subject`, and `Class`, and I want to establish a three-way relationship between them.

According to the [Sequelize documentation](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/advanced-many-to-many/#many-to-many-to-many-relationships-and-beyond), this can be accomplished by associating `Teacher` and `Subject` through `TeacherSubject` and then joining `Class` with `TeacherSubject` through another junction table, `TeacherSubjectClass`. However, I need to include an `id` field for `TeacherSubject` so that the `Class` model can reference it.

Is it possible to create `TeacherSubjectClass` directly without first creating `TeacherSubject`?

Comment: When you create through table you include id column anyways. I'd stick to this solution.